# how to show success value before ajax jquery complete from php page

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

This is my ajax code:

```
$(".content").empty();
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'xyz.php',
    data: $('.chk:checked').serialize(),
    success: function(data) {

        $(".content").append(data);

    }
});
```

My php Page:

```
 <?php

  echo "1 <br/>";
  echo "2 <br/>;
  echo "3 <br/>;
  echo "4 <br/>;

  ?>
```

When I run my script its appending :

```
1
2
3
4
```

my question is, when I put break point at line 3 it should show  :

```
1
2
```

But these values are only showing after ajax complete. I need to show PHP values at real time. Before ajax complete. how  can do that. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Multiple ajax requests or a socket connection would help.

Comment: What do you mean by a 'break point' at line 3?

Comment: @progrAmmar i'm using visual studio code with xdebug

Comment: Oh I see, well in that case, if you want realtime data you should consider working with websockets. Ajax will only post the response once it gets all of the response from the server

Comment: I have seen a php syntax in your PHP code. Can you confirm if it is working ?

Answer (score 0):

Any script you execute (render/append) on client side using ajax request will be executed once the ajax is complete.

Here in your code you are sending a request on sever to get some value, you can display the value on the client once the ajax is completed and it received the response(value) from from server.

**You can not put debug on the server code and see the value on client side. using ajax till request is completed**

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't really get the concept.

So if you do an ajax call, it fetches a page, and provide the information

In your case, your back-end (php) response with 1 page with 4 "echo's". With other words, **you don't fetch the page 4 times but once** with 4 integers.